# Plotting a circle equations in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, geometry, equation

I have a problem to plot a circle equation in Julia.

I'm trying to plot these two equations:

- 2y^2 + x^2 = 2
- (x-1)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1/4

At this time, the only solution i found is using [ImplicitEquations.jl](https://github.com/jverzani/ImplicitEquations.jl) but with this, the resulting plot is not satisfying (it looks like filled wit separate pixels):

[image: Plotted circle]

(See [here](https://calculuswithjulia.github.io/derivatives/implicit_differentiation.html).)

Is there a better solution to do it?

```
f(x,y) = 2*y^2+x^2 - 2
g(x,y) = (x-1)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 - 1/4
```

I need to compare these two equations to zero.

Comment: Hi, I tried to make your post a bit nicer to read, please check it again. You should probably still add a minimal example showing how to reproduce this plot, and which libraries to include.

Comment: That blocking is an artifact of the algorithm. You might try `https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalConstraintProgramming.jl` as well, it renders a bit faster Alternatively, you might increase the values of `N` and `M` to `plot` from 8. The larger the value, the smaller the blocking but the longer it takes to render.

Answer (score 2):

with Plots you can do

```
x = -2:0.01:2
contour(f.(x, x'), levels = [0])
contour!(g.(x, x'), levels = [0])
```

admittedly this is not the most intuitive interface - I would have hoped for

```
contour([f,g], levels = 0)
```

You're welcome to open an issue on the Plots.jl repo.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the old-fashioned parametric equations approach:

```
x = xbar + r*cos(t)
x = ybar + r*sin(t)
```

where you vary `t` from 0 to 2*pi?  (`xbar,ybar`) is the centre and `r` is the radius.